Decomposition of function over finite set into injective and surjective functions
Let $A$ be a finite set and $B$ a countably infinite set. Is it possible to write any function $f: A \to A$ as two functions, one injective, $\varphi: B \to B$ and one surjective $\mu : B \to A$ with $f(X) = \mu \circ \phi \circ \mu^{-1}(X)$ for $X \subseteq A$? I feel as though this shouldn't be hard to prove or find a counterexample, but my leads are going nowhere. Thank you.

What do you mean by $\mu^{-1}$? The map $\mu$ can't be bijective.

@Tri, This is talking about preimages and images, not bare functions. I'll modify the question to be more clear.

The answer to this question, as it's written is no. Here's why:
Consider the case when $X$ is the entire set $A$, and $f(A)≠A$. That is, $f$ is not surjective. Then, if $\mu$ is surjective, $\mu^{-1}(A)=B$. Next, since $\phi$ is bijective, $\phi(\mu^{-1}(A))=\phi(B)=B$. Thus, $\,\mu(\phi(\mu^{-1}(A)))=\mu(B)=A$, again because $\mu$ is surjective. Since, we assumed $f(A)≠A$, we see that $f(A)≠\mu(\phi(\mu^{-1}(A)))$, disproving the claim.
Now, we immediately want to ask ourselves what happens if $f$ is surjective. In this case, the claim is true!!
Let's enumerate the elements of $A$ as $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_{|A|}$. Now, consider a "partition" of $B$ into $|A|$ distinct subsets, $B_1,B_2,\dots,B_{|A|}$. For example, if $A=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$, and $B=\mathbb{Z}$, we could partition $B$ into the $5$ congruence classes modulo $5$. In fact, the only necessary condition for such a partition to be created is that $|B|≥|A|$. However, we will use the fact that $B$ is countably infinite to say that all our partitions must be the same size. This is a restriction that we're allowed to make. (A quick way to prove this is to say that if $B$ is countably infinite, it can be enumerated, and so we can simply place each element into the partition assigned to its index modulo $|A|$)
Now, we can define $\mu$ such that if $b\in B_i$, $\mu(b)=a_i$. In other words, $\mu(B_i)=\{a_i\}$. Based on our contruction, this is clearly a surjection. Because $f$ is a surjection and $A$ is a finite set, we must also have that $f$ is an injection. This gives us the powerful fact $f$ simply permutes the elements of $A$ around. Thus, if $f(a_i)=a_j$, define $\phi(B_i)=B_j$. Since all the partitions are the same size, this mapping is injective (and even bijective). This can be seen as $\phi$ permuting the partitions of $B$ the exact same way $f$ permutes the elements of $A$.
Now, we have a full picture. $f$ will shuffle the elements of $X$ around. $\mu^{-1}$ will grab each element of $X$, relating them to their respective partitions. $\phi$ will then shuffle those partitions exactly how $f$ did it. Finally, $\mu$ will send the new partitions back to their corresponding new elements in the image of $f$. Thus, $f(X)=\mu(\phi(\mu^{-1}(X)))$. $\square$
So, we have proven the following alternative claim:
Let $A$ be a finite set and $B$ be a countably infinite set. Let $f:A \to A$ be surjective. Then, there exists a surjective $\mu:B \to A$ and bijective $\phi:B \to B$ such that for all $X \subseteq A$, $f(X)=\mu \circ \phi \circ \mu^{-1}(X)$.
As an extra little bonus, this also works if $B$ is finite and $|A|$ divides |B|, because the only reason we needed $B$ to be countably infinite was to ensure all the partitions are the same size.
